# John Papa "Y165" and Tests

Tags: angularjs, maven, testing, jasmine-maven-plugin

My project has a structure like the Y165 Recommendation of John Papa.
The web project works fine (So my app.modile.js is correct and my modules statements are too).

The problem is with the tests.

I use jasmine-maven-plugin with PhamtomJS (before the refactoring all was OK).

Right now I have an error : **[$injector:nomod] Module 'xxxxxxxx' is not available ! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module enure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

At the beginning I make a : beforeEach(module('app')) so normally my modules should be seen like in the web project.

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunkr demonstrating the issue? I just did a quick test with dependant modules and it should work fine. My guess is that you haven't included one or more scripts which contain the module that angular can't load. How are you running the tests? Are you using Karma?

Comment: Here is a Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/nIQvNfbz7Sjz1ov3kch7 - My explanations in the README.md and i join a pom.xml